# wall time extension in Condor

Tags: condor

I have problems while submitting jobs with Condor.

My job(s) is basically a shell script that runs a c++ program.

When submitting job(s) with Condor, my job(s) never manages to finish because

"Job was aborted by the user.
        Job removed by SYSTEM_PERIODIC_REMOVE due to wall time exceeded allowed max." (from the log file)
From the .out file I can clearly see that my job starts to do what it's supposed to, but it doesn't get to finish.

How can I modify this wall time?
Please note that the job(s) needs less than 1h to finish, so I am not looking for something particularly performing.

Thank you all for the help
Cheers
Matteo

Answer (score 1):

SYSTEM_PERIODIC_REMOVE is an expression an administrator can set to automatically remove some jobs that meet some criteria.  Apparently, the system administrator of your pool has set this to try to remove jobs that have run for some amount of time.  Can you talk to your administrator and see what the limits are, and if they can be extended for you?